# World list in message.content

Tags: python, discord.py

Hello i'm trying to make a custom bot for telegram in Python.
i'm looking to use a world list combined with in message content.

```
world_list = ['home', 'house', 'maison']

@client.listen('on_message')
async def on_message(message):
     if message.content in world_list:
        await message.channel.send("i'm coming home")
```

with this code if a use write

> i would like to go home

bot remain silent, it work only if the message is a single world of the list, how i can fix it?

Comment: This is a simple bug. Loop through the content, and check if any of the words are in the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
>>> message = "I would like to go home"
>>> words = ["home", ...]
>>> message in words
False
```

You're comparing the WHOLE message content to the list, if the list was something like this `["I would like to go home", ...]` the result would be `True`, but it's not, for that you can use the `any` function

```py
>>> message = "I would like to go home"
>>> words = ["home", ...]
>>> any(word in message for word in words)
True
>>> message = "Something else"
>>> any(word in message for word in words)
False
```

It's the same as

```py
>>> def words_in_message(content: str, words: list[str]) -> bool:
...     for word in words:
...         if word in content:
...             return True
...     return False
>>> 
>>> message = "I would like to go home"
>>> words = ["home", ...]
>>> words_in_message(message, words)
True
>>> message = "Something else"
>>> words_in_message(message, words)
False
```

Your code should look like this

```py
world_list = ['home', 'house', 'maison']

@client.listen('on_message')
async def on_message(message):
     if any(word in message.content for word in words):
        await message.channel.send("i'm coming home")
```

Comment: thank a lot. i'm just new to python and i feel really dumb when i can't manage this dumb task

Comment: haha no worries :), it’s not the first thing you learn in python, also remember to accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

You must check single words for existence in `world_list`

```
any([word in world_list for word in message.split(' ')])
```

returns `True` or `False`
so use it like this

```
...    
if any([word in world_list for word in message.split(' ')]):
        await message.channel.send("i'm coming home")
```

Comment: A better option would be looping through the `word_list` instead of splitting the message and looping through that, if a message contains something like `this $house is big` the result will be `False` even though there's `home` in the content

Comment: Yes, you're right if it should react on partly strings. Also did you make mistake in `$house` or it have some point? I would expect `$home`.

Comment: Small mistake haha, sorry

Answer (score 0):

you are currently checking whether *the whole message content is on the list*. But you are trying to achieve another thing *checking whether any of the list items is in the message content.*
try doing it like this,

```
world_list = ['home', 'house', 'maison']

@client.listen('on_message')
async def on_message(message):
    for word in world_list:
        if word in message.content:
            await message.channel.send("i'm coming home")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the list;

```py
world_list = ['home', 'house', 'maison']

for word in world_list:
    if word in message.content:
        await message.channel.send("i'm coming home")
        break
```